# How to convert Double back into Timestamp from Firebase Database

Tags: ios, firebase

When I store a Timestamp into my database it ends up looking something like:

```
1612137962960
```

How do I convert this double back into a time stamp when observing from the database? I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
   // Get user value
   let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
   let dateUserJoined = value?["time created"] as? Double ?? 0
   let timestamp = Timestamp(dateUserJoined)
}
```

But this doesn't work. How do I initialize a new time stamp from the value stored in firebase?

Thanks

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: I don’t think you can initialize a time stamp from a double

Comment: Did you see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp)?

Comment: Yes, thanks. What I am confused about is what this long value represents. Is it the seconds or nanoseconds?

Comment: The value is milliseconds since 1/1/1970. You have to divide by 1000 to get the seconds and the remainder * 1000 are the nanoseconds. Or create  a `Date` and use the date initializer.